# mysql : count and inner join in same query

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables

```
users, jobs, proposals

users(id, username, address, email)

jobs(id, title, description, etc)

proposals(id, userid, jobid, date)
```

A users can apply to many jobs and

a single job can be applied by many users

proposals table stores information of who applied to which job

```
select j.* from proposals p inner join jobs j on p.jobid = j.id where p.userid=$userid
```

The above query lists all the jobs applied by the specific user. Now I want to show for each job how many people have applied in same query, is it possible

I tried

```
 select j.*, count(select * from proposals where jobid =j.id) as count from proposals p inner join jobs j on p.jobid = j.id where p.userid=$userid
```

also

```
select j.*, (select count(*) from proposals where jobid =j.id) as count from proposals p inner join jobs j on p.jobid = j.id where p.userid=$userid
```

I know the above queries is wrong but this will give some idea.

Comment: you need a `GROUP BY`

Comment: @niceman but I don't know where to put?

Comment: Your last query seems to being correct which can get what you want. Does it not work?

Comment: Please show sample data and expected output.  It isn't clear to me what you want here.

Comment: @ Forward yes bro it works now... for some reason it throwed some error previously

Comment: even if it works subqueries isn't the way to go , group by will be much simpler and faster

Comment: @vSuguma ***Note:*** `count` is reserved word in mysql, you should escape it with backticks when you use it as alias.

Comment: @niceman I know bro group by is best, but I dont know how to use group by in my query

Comment: downvoters should explain, why they are downvoting, I feel like somebody is downvoting all my questions

Comment: @vSugumar the deleted answer in my opinion was correct, and so is the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `group by`, also a subquery is necessary, try following:

```
select j.*, t.cnt
from jobs j 
join proposals p on p.jobid = j.id
left join (
    select jobid, count(userid) as cnt
    from proposals
    group by jobid
) t on t.jobid = j.id 
where p.userid = $userid
```

***Note:*** This query may not have better performance than your last query.

Comment: why the subquery is necessary ?!!

Comment: @niceman You should figure out what the op want to get firstly.

Comment: I still don't understand why the below answer(after replacing `j.title` with `j.*`) work !!

Comment: @niceman Nope, below answer just get applicants of all job, not the jobs which a specified user `$useid` applied. That's the point.

Comment: @vSugumar while I'm not the downvoter of your question I can see why the downvote :P, "for every job how many people applied" should have been "for each job how many times a specific user applied" so the same user can apply to same job multiple times

Answer (score 1):

Isn't `group by` what you are searching for ?

```
select j.title, count(*) as number_of_applicants 
from jobs j join proposals 
on j.id = p.jobid 
group by p.jobid;
```

It might not work perfectly since I don't have the datas to test it, but try on this path !